# Set locale: Vue is not defined

Tags: instance, vue.js, vue-component

In my main.js file I register Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import App from './components/App.vue';

// Register plugins
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueI18n);

// Create router
const router = new VueRouter({
  history: true,
  saveScrollPosition: true,
});

router.start({
  components: { App },
}, 'body');
```

Now I want to get a translation file in my App.Vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  ready() {
    /* Set Language */
    Vue.locale('nl', function setLanguage() {
      return this.$http({
        url: '/src/language/nl_NL.js',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Vue.locale('nl', response);
        Vue.config.lang = 'nl';
      }).then(() => {
        alert('Error');
      });
    });
  },

};
</script>
```

I got the error: `'Vue' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're simply not importing `Vue` into you `App.vue`?

Comment: Router.start automatically creates a Vue instance.

Comment: You mean it injects the `Vue` variable into the component scope? Can you give me a link to the documentation?

Comment: No, I think I understood you wrong, sorry. I mean, I only start a new Vue instance in main.js. The code above is all I have in App.Vue (except one html line with `<router-start></router-start>` but that makes no sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you're missing an import statement for vue in you `App.vue`, as vue doesn't automatically inject itself into the vue files AFAIK:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'; // <--

export default {
  ready() {
    /* Set Language */
    Vue.locale('nl', function setLanguage() {
      return this.$http({
        url: '/src/language/nl_NL.js',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Vue.locale('nl', response);
        Vue.config.lang = 'nl';
      }).then(() => {
        alert('Error');
      });
    });
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Newbie question: but is it ok to import Vue twice (in App.Vue and in main.js)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I imagine that you're using either browserify or webpack to bundle the files, and both of them create separate scopes for each file that you have. So the `Vue` in `main.js` is not available in `App.vue`.

Comment: Thank you. But it's not that the file is imported twice this way; causing my application to have much more code?

Comment: No, the `Vue` code is only included once in your code bundle, but the same code is made available at different locations in your code (e.g. `main.js` and `App.js`) as the variable `Vue`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. If you want, you can have a look at your bundled JS file, there you should only see the vue code once, but multiple places requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can understand from your code your Vue app is being created before you make Vue use all the dependecies. You should create the app instance only after you do all those Vue.use(*). It should do it.  Also, it would be better to use `this` inside the component to refer to right instance of Vue. Inside your methods you can do `self = this`so you protect yourself against scope issues. Inside child components you may use this.$root to refer to app component. I hope this helps.